# How can I get access to multiple values of nested JSON object?

Tags: json, object, nested

I try to access to my `data` json file:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Maria","project":[{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Cats"}]}
```

This is my approach:

```
data[0].name;
```

But like this I get only the result:

```
Animals
```

But I would need the result:

```
Animals, Cats
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your actual data object, then `data[0].name` would give you "Maria". If I'm reading this right, though, you want to get all the names from the `project` array. You can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it fairly easily. Note the use of an ES6 [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to quickly and easily take in the object and return its name.

```js
var bigObject = [{"id":1,"name":"Maria","project":[{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Cats"}]}];
var smallObject = [{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Cats"}];

console.log("Getting the names from the full array/data structure: "+bigObject[0].project.map(obj => obj.name))
console.log("Getting the names from just the project array: "+smallObject.map(obj => obj.name))
```

EDIT: As per your comment on the other answer, you said you needed to use the solution in this function:

```
"render": function (data, type, row) {if(Array.isArray(data)){return data.name;}}
```

To achieve this, it looks like you should use my bottom solution of the first snippet like so:

```js
var data = [{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Cats"}];

function render(data, type, row){
  if(Array.isArray(data)){
    return data.map(obj => obj.name);
  }
};

console.log("Render returns \""+render(data)+"\" as an array.");
```

Comment: @Jarla Glad I could help! Good luck on whatever you're using this for. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing only the name property of 0th index of project array.
To access all object at a time you need to loop over the array.
You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this.

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"name":"Maria","project":[{"id":5,"name":"Animals"},{"id":6,"name":"Cats"}]}]

var out = data[0].project.map(project => project.name).toString()

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is confusing me, because `data` in my example is actually replacing `project` and in your example you have data and project two different things. I do not know how to transfer this now into my code `"render": function (data, type, row) {if(Array.isArray(data)){return data.name;}}`

Comment: as per your example. If data is the provided json, then  `data[0].name` is `Maria` not `Animals`. If you are getting `Animals` it means data is actually `your given json => project`

Comment: if data is projects array: just do `data.map(project => project.name).toString()`

Comment: data = project. This would mean data.map(data => data.name).toString()

Comment: Is it possible to just write this `data[,].name`

Comment: `data[,].name` this will give unexpected token error.

Comment: @Jarla No, you cannot use square bracket notation to achieve what you want (don't worry, everyone's made that same error). You have to use some other method like a for loop or `array.map`.

Comment: @Jarla well it should be

Comment: `data.map(project => project.name).toString()` and `data.map(data => data.name).toString()`both are similar only. I am passing a function inside map, and you can define function with any param name. Check arrow function for detail.
In normal function expression `data.map(function(project){return project.name}).toString()`